# Strange Precision of Keras Binary Accuracy Metric with 100 images

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm using Keras to train a CNN to classify some images. I currently have a training data size of 100 images, but the accuracy metric gives me results like 0.8021- How is this possible, when Keras computes binary accuracy as the mean of the number of images correctly classified?

If the model classifies 80 images correctly at the end of an epoch, should the accuracy not be 0.80? How does it get to the this level of precision?

Comment: Have you considered that its just floating point imprecision?